# Почему не редиректятся файлы zip/png/jpg/gif?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Столкнулся с непонятным для меня глюком.

Есть папка с файлами `/sites/default/files/quest/` (да-да, Drupal).
В этой папке куча папочек с вложенными файлами.
Нужно редиректить всё и вся при обращении к файлам в этой папке.

Есть .htaccess в корне сайта с вот такими штучками:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^sites/default/files/quest/(.*)/(.*)$ /files/quest/$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Нормально работает, редиректит всех на `/files/quest/*/*.*`.
До тех пора пока не запросишь файлы `zip/png/jpg/gif`, все остальные файлы редиректятся успешно, все, кроме zip архивов и image/*, ngnixa нет.

В логах `mod_rewrite` есть только записи об обращении к файлам не zip, image/*, логов с zip и изображениями нет, как будто rewrite вообще не срабатывает для этих файлов.

Лог аксесс:

> "GET
> /sites/default/files/quest/31367/tekst_email.zip
> **HTTP/1.1" 200 946** "http://z-ok.ru/quest/31164" - и нет
> редиректа, 200соточка :(
>
> "GET
> /sites/default/files/quest/31367/tehzadanie_polnoe.docx
> **HTTP/1.0" 301** 336 "http://z-ok.ru/quest/31164" - и есть
> редирект 301 :)

Как так то?

**Обновление**

[[@Get](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get), Боюсь, что вы не правы и говорите про !-f. 
Комментирование строки ни к каким изменениям не привело.
Еще раз:

```
test.xlsx - редиректит  
test.csv  - редиректит  
test.doc  - редиректит  
test.docx  - редиректит  
test.zip  - не редиректит  
test.png  - не редиректит
```

> К файлам, которые можно отдать без обработки сервером

csv и doc у нас нынче сервером обрабатываются? Спасибо за потраченное время.

Answer (score 1):

Строка

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

означает не применять правило

```
 RewriteRule ^sites/default/files/quest/(.*)/(.*)$ /files/quest/$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

к файлам, которые можно отдать без обработки сервером (картинки, тектовые, архивы и т.п. но не php)

**Обновление**

Конечно, извиняюсь, не увидел отсутствие `!` перед `-f`

Возможно, по пути до `/sites/default/files/quest/` лежат другие `htaccess` и перекрывают тот, что в корне.

Answer (score 0):

В Друпале есть "ускоренный" обработчик 404 ошибки. Если в запросе он находит "ненужные" расширения файла, не разбираясь дальше выбрасывает на страничку 404 Апача. Список "ненужных" расширений лежит в файле settings.php (обычно в папке sites/default).
Думаю, ваша проблема в этом.

Comment: drupal 6. в settings.php ничего такого нет.
Боюсь дело не в 404, т.к. в моем случае редиректа НЕ происходит вообще.